# leet code problem 2 (add two numbers) runtime error when using malloc

Tags: c, struct, sum, singly-linked-list, function-definition

I get this error when I run the code. Could someone explain why?

> Line 70: Char 15: runtime error: member access within misaligned address 0xbebebebebebebebe for type 'struct ListNode', which requires 8 byte alignment [ListNode.c]
> 0xbebebebebebebebe: note: pointer points here
> <memory cannot be printed>

```
/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * struct ListNode {
 *     int val;
 *     struct ListNode *next;
 * };
 */


struct ListNode* addTwoNumbers(struct ListNode* l1, struct ListNode* l2)
{
    struct ListNode * head1=l1;
    struct ListNode * head2=l2;
    struct ListNode *toReturn=malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode));

//it is complainig about this temp
    struct ListNode *temp = NULL;
    int carry,total=0;
    
    while(head1 !=NULL || head2!=NULL)
    {
        temp = malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode));  
        
        if(carry==0)
        {
            total = head1->val + head2->val; 
        }
        else if(carry!=0)
        {
            total = head1->val + head2->val+carry;   
        }
      
        if(total ==10)
        {
            total =0;
            carry = 1; 
        }
        else if(total>10)
        {
            total = total -10;
            carry =1;
        }
        toReturn-> val = total;
        toReturn->next = temp;
        
        head1= head1->next;
        head2=head2->next;
    }
    return toReturn;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre] and describe what the program is supposd to do and what your concept of achieving that is.

Comment: https://leetcode.com/problems/add-two-numbers/discuss/278012/need-help-with-c-code

Comment: Strangely, your code is not the same as the code posted in that discussion, but the error message is identical, including the line and column numbers.

Comment: If this `//This line is causing runtime error` refers to the line with `malloc()` I doubt it. Otherwise please clarify which line is meant.

Comment: @Yunnosch I ran the code again and it is complaining about  struct ListNode *temp = NULL; The error is related to it

Comment: Sorry, but that comment has even decreased clarity for me.

Comment: @Yunnosch I edited my code and removed the old comment and added a new one.

Comment: I still doubt that line to cause any problem directly. What makes you think that this is the line which causes the runtime error? Please see my very first comment.

Comment: @Yunnosch I am mallocing inside the loop??

Comment: Are you asking me? Looking at `while (...) { ... malloc(..); }` I 'd say yes you are.

Comment: @Yunnosch yes because I am not sure if we could malloc inside the loop

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/21/find-a-simpler-problem/ and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ is the only helpful contribution I have for you in a situation where you seem to be very unclear about what you are doing and just copying a code fragment and an imprecise error report. (And I blame challenge and contest sites.) More generally, for asking questions on StackOverflow please take the [tour] and read [ask] and [mre] (you seem to have ignored the first time I provided that last link). Good luck.

Comment: Shouldn't `carry` be initialized to a value before using it in the first iteration of the while-loop? eg. `int carry = 0, total = 0;` You are currently just checking and/or adding the "random" value of `carry` in the first while-iteration.

Answer (score 2):

Warning, doing

> ```
> while(head1 !=NULL || head2!=NULL)
> ```

*head1* or *head2* can be NULL when you dereference them in the body of the loop to get *val*

you probably wanted :

```
while(head1 !=NULL && head2!=NULL)
```

---

> Line 70: Char 15: runtime error: member access within misaligned address 0xbebebebebebebebe for type 'struct ListNode', which requires 8 byte alignment [ListNode.c]
> 0xbebebebebebebebe: note: pointer points here

An other problem in your function is your function returns a non initialized cell :

- if both *head1* and *head2* are NULL before the loop you return a newly allocated *ListNode* where both *val* and (worst) *next* are non initialized
- if by chance the lists received in argument have the same length you return a list of two cells where the second cell has both *val* and (worst) *next* are non initialized. Out of that all the cells allocated through `temp = malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode));` except the last one are lost (memory leak)

If you call again the function with a list returned by itself you will try to dereference a non initialized field *next* with an undefined behavior explaining your error

---

Out of that

Why are you doing

> ```
> struct ListNode * head1=l1;
> struct ListNode * head2=l2;
> ```

for nothing because you do not use *l1* and *l2* later, just work with these variables without introducing the new ones.

Why that complicated code :

> ```
> if(carry==0)
> {
>     total = head1->val + head2->val; 
> }
> else if(carry!=0)
> {
>     total = head1->val + head2->val+carry;   
> }
> ```

rather than just

```
total = head1->val + head2->val + carry;
```

Visibly you do decimal addition and *val* values between 0 and 9, so why that complicated code :

> ```
> if(total ==10)
> {
>     total =0;
>     carry = 1; 
> }
> else if(total>10)
> {
>     total = total -10;
>     carry =1;
> }
> ```

rather than just

```
if (total>10)
{
    total = total - 10;
    carry = 1;
}
```

and you also missed an *else* to reset *carry* to 0 :

```
if (total>10)
{
    total = total - 10;
    carry = 1;
}
else
  carry = 0;
```

Your algorithm also have to manage the case the two lists do not have the same length, that can be done in several ways, to manage the case one of the two lists is NULL inside the *while* or adding code after the *while*

Comment: the linked lists could be of different sizes

Comment: @Legend yes but whatever, you cannot go after the end of a list

Comment: @Legend and as I said the other error comes probably because you missed to set *field* in (at least) a list cell

Comment: I added && instead of || but it is still complaining about it

Comment: @Legend becase as I said in my answer **you reach a non or wrongly initialized field *next* for one of the list you go through**

Comment: yeah makes sense now. I need to check if lists are NULL. Thanks

Comment: @Legend you do not understand, is not only to *check* but also to *set/assign* the field *next* to NULL for the last cell of your lists. You have several errors in your code, not only the one at the beginning of my answer

Comment: I get that but those lists are provided with the question. So, I am assuming they already made it NULL. I will definitely revise my code. Thanks

Comment: Hi bruno. At truly valiant effort at helping. But I am afraid that the need to guess and the inconsistent info by OP, which you have noticed yourself, together with the declined MRE makes answering here futile. I would upvote the effort, but the future helpfulness of this Q/A is very questionable. Good luck.

Comment: in your question there is nothing concerning the call of the function, we know nothing about the lists received in argument

Comment: @Yunnosch yes I know ... at least the wrong condition in the *while* is fixed

Answer (score 1):

Your function has several serious problems.

For example if the both passed to the function pointers are null pointers then the function returns a pointer to an uninitialized node

```
struct ListNode* addTwoNumbers(struct ListNode* l1, struct ListNode* l2)
{
    struct ListNode * head1=l1;
    struct ListNode * head2=l2;
    struct ListNode *toReturn=malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode));
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^    
 
//it is complainig about this temp
    struct ListNode *temp = NULL;
    int carry,total=0;
    
    while(head1 !=NULL || head2!=NULL)
    {
        //...
    }

    return toReturn;
}
```

So this memory allocation in the beginning of the function

```
struct ListNode *toReturn=malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode));
```

does not make a sense.

If one of the pointers `head1` or `head2` is equal to `NULL` then this while loop

```
    while(head1 !=NULL || head2!=NULL)
    {
        //...
    }
```

invokes undefined behavior because within the loop you are accessing memory using a null pointer as for example in this statement

```
total = head1->val + head2->val;
```

You should write the condition in the while loop like

```
    while(head1 !=NULL && head2!=NULL)
    {
        //...
    }
```

Also the last node of the created list also stays uninitialized

```
while(head1 !=NULL || head2!=NULL)
{
    temp = malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode));  

    //...

    toReturn-> val = total;
    toReturn->next = temp;
    
    head1= head1->next;
    head2=head2->next;
}
```

Also you are always changing the same node pointed to by the pointer `toReturn`

```
    toReturn-> val = total;
    toReturn->next = temp;
```

So the function produces memory leaks and the list is not being built.

Numerous if statements are redundant. For example instead of

```
if(carry==0)
{
    total = head1->val + head2->val; 
}
else if(carry!=0)
{
    total = head1->val + head2->val+carry;   
}
```

you could just write one statement

```
total = head1->val + head2->val+carry;
```

You need to append the function with a code that processes one of the lists when other list is empty that is when either `head1` or `head2` is equal to `NULL`.

Also the data member `val` of the structure `ListNode` should have the type `unsigned int` if you suppose that lists will contain unsigned numbers, Otherwise you need to store also the sign of the stored number.

Here is a demonstrative program that shows how the function `addTwoNumbers` can be written.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct ListNode 
{
    unsigned int val;
    struct ListNode *next;
};

int set( struct ListNode **head, unsigned long long n )
{
    const unsigned int Base = 10;
    
    while ( *head )
    {
        struct ListNode *tmp = *head;
        head = &( *head )->next;
        free( tmp );
    }
    
    int success = 1;
    struct ListNode **current = head;
    
    do
    {
        *current = malloc( sizeof( struct ListNode ) );
        success = *current != NULL;
        
        if ( success )
        {
            ( *current )->val  = n % Base;
            ( *current )->next = NULL;
            current = &( *current )->next;
        }
    } while ( success && ( n /= Base ) );
    
    
    if ( !success )
    {
        while ( *head )
        {
            struct ListNode *tmp = *head;
            head = &( *head )->next;
            free( tmp );
        }
    }
    
    return success;
}

FILE * display( const struct ListNode *head, FILE *fp )
{
    if ( head )
    {
        display( head->next, fp );
        fprintf( fp, "%u", head->val );
    }
    
    return fp;
}

struct ListNode * addTwoNumbers( const struct ListNode *head1, 
                                 const struct ListNode *head2 )
{
    const unsigned Base = 10;

    struct ListNode *result = NULL;
    struct ListNode **current = &result;
    
    unsigned int carry = 0;
    int success = 1;
    
    while ( success && ( head1 ||  head2 ) )
    {
        *current = malloc( sizeof( struct ListNode ) );
        success = *current != NULL;
        
        if ( success )
        {
            ( *current )->next = NULL;
            unsigned int sum = carry + ( head1 ? head1->val : 0 ) + 
                                       ( head2 ? head2->val : 0 );
            
            ( *current )->val = sum % Base;
            carry = !( sum < Base );
            
            if ( head1 ) head1 = head1->next;
            if ( head2 ) head2 = head2->next;
            current = &( *current )->next;
        }
    }
    
    if ( !success )
    {
        while ( result )
        {
            struct ListNode *tmp = result;
            result = result->next;
            free( tmp );
        }
    }
    
    return result;
}

int main(void) 
{
    struct ListNode *head1 = NULL;
    
    set( &head1, 123456789 );
    
    fputc( '\n', display( head1, stdout ) );
    
    struct ListNode *head2 = NULL;
    
    set( &head2, 123456789 );
    
    fputc( '\n', display( head2, stdout ) );

    struct ListNode *sum = addTwoNumbers( head1, head2 );
    
    fputc( '\n', display( sum, stdout ) );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
123456789
123456789
246913578
```

If you want that the list could contain also negative numbers then the first node of the list could contain the sign: 0 - the number is non-negative, 1 - the number is negative. Another approach is to store signed digits in nodes of the list.